# Is it possible to create a has many relationship between a pivot table and another table?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, pivot

There is pivot table called `order_product` like this:

```
order_id | product_id | quantity | price
1          2            3          1500
```

I need to add a serial for each order_product, but it's not possible because there  is a `number` column and each product have it's own serial.

What's the best way to solve this issue?

Is it good idea to add a id to the `order_product` table like this:

```
id | order_id | product_id | price
1    6          2            1500
```

and create another table called `serials` like this?:

```
id | order_product_id | serial
1    1                  6545154
2    1                  123
3    1                  456
```

If there is no other way, can I implement it with an ORM like Eloquent?

Comment: serial belongs to each order_product or product?

Comment: @Zartosht Serial belongs to each order_product, each sold product has it's own serial

Comment: why not add a extra column to order_product table named serial?

Comment: @Zartosht Because there is a quantity field so if the quantity is 2 means this row represents two product and it has two serial numbers

Comment: @Ali can you tell me what is the relation between Product and Serial models?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Refrigerator type A has many serials so the refrigerator that we sold to Andy has it's own serial (one serial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a new model named `OrderProducts` (or anything you want), in this model add this protected field:

```
protected $table = "order_product";
```

after add cast to this model for field named `serials`:

```
protected $casts = [
        "serials" => "array"
    ];
```

now your serials should be an array of sold product's serial.